# Node JS: Promise resolve value is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save multiple documents(via `Mongoose`) through a recursive method.

I created a `Promise` which resolves a method `admin_save_choices()` to save an `Array` of documents and finally return an `Array` of `Objects` after saving the documents or error message. Along with that when a document is saved in callback it recursively call itself(`admin_save_choices()`) until `Array` element exists.

Here is the `Promise` -

```
        let choices_object_array_promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          let choices_object_array = admin_save_choices(choices, timestamp);

          resolve(choices_object_array);
        });

        choices_object_array_promise.then(function(result){

          console.log(result);
          res.status(200);
          res.json('success');
        }).catch(function(error) {
          res.status(400);
          res.json('error');
        });
```

Here is the method -

```
var admin_save_choices = function(choices, timestamp) {
    let choices_object_array = [];

    let choice = choices.shift();

    if (typeof choice === "undefined")
      return choices_object_array;

    let choice_information = {
      choice: choice,
      created_time: timestamp
    };

    let save_choice_promise = choiceModel.save_choice(choice_information);

    save_choice_promise.then(function(choice_result_object) {

      choices_object_array.push(choice_result_object);

      admin_save_choices(choices, timestamp);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      return 'error';
    });
}
```

**All documents are being saved successfully** except I don't get the result come back to `choices_object_array_promise.then(` callback.

It is showing `undefined` in `console.log(result)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off-topic. Though this is not directly related to the error. Your code contains a few common Promises Antipatterns. The worst one is ["The Collection Kerfuffle"](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#the-collection-kerfuffle:8f173b15e2d19515fdc8ce931ae539c0) Sequential saving looks like this `const save = choice=> all => choiceModel.save_choice({choice}).then(item => all.concat(item)); return choices.reduce((saving, item) => saving.then(save(item)), Promise.resolve([])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `admin_save_choices` do not return anything.

I guess your trying to return the array of admin, maybe this is what you want to do :

```
// inside admin_save_choices 
return save_choice_promise
  .then(function(choice_result_object) {
    choices_object_array.push(choice_result_object);
    return admin_save_choices(choices, timestamp);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return error;
  });
}

let choices_object_array_fn = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  resolve(admin_save_choices(choices, timestamp));
});
```

Edit: For anti anti-pattern sake :)

Comment: @Paulpro The comment was about a new code in the answer itself. Check the edit history it was like this `new Promise(async function(resolve, reject)` and was corrected (I hope due to my comment :)) BTW I still think it would be great to provide antipattern free solution.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Oh, my bad. I did not see the edit history.

Comment: BTW I think the code should be `return admin_save_choices(choices, timestamp);` to keep the promise chain :)

Comment: When pattern matters :)